# How to prepare the string which can be passed to MySql SP using node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_getNames`(
iName varchar(255)
)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('
        select distinct Name, Age, Grade, Class from tblStudents
        where Name in (', iName, ')
    ');
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

I'm calling the SP like below and getting the data:

```
CALL `db_datauniverse`.`proc_getNames` ('\'smith\',\'john\',\'doe\'');
```

My question is how can I pass this kind of a value via code (like node.js).
I tried to pass comma(,) separated values like **'smith,john,doe'**, but it didn't work.

Could you please help me with the correct structure to pass to SP?

Comment: Maybe you should learn about prepared statements for Mysql in Node.js. That will solve your problems and also will avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I just had to prepare a string like the following: "'smith','john','doe'".

Wrap every element with quotes and join them with ','.